# Lexicographically

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I came across a question and couldnt solve it, can anyone help me?
question goes as- Given a string  find a lexicographically smallest subsequenceof lenght 'X'.

Comment: This is not a C++ question.  Also [why "can you help me" is not a question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Step 1: figure out how to make a sliding window of length X over your given string. `std::string::substr` can do that. Step 2: figure out how to count the number of b's. Step 3: use the default std::string comparison to find the lexicographically smallest substring. Show a bit of effort and tell us where you get stuck in each step.

Comment: @Botje , actually, we are supposed to find a subsequence, not a substring.

Comment: Missed that, my mistake. That means the complexity rises from O(n) to O(n choose x) in the brute force case. I would start by implementing that. Once you have that working, look into dynamic programming to claw back O(n) complexity.